# Optimización de Columna Tipo String

Tags: python, pandas

Les platico, tengo la siguiente columna llamada "ASSET" es de tipo string y tiene 10 o 11 caracteres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y con esta columna genero otra llamada "CLASE" con el siguiente código:

```
join["CLASE"] = ""
for row in join["ASSET"]:
    join["CLASE"] = [row[0:3] if len(row)==11 else row[0:4] for row in join["ASSET"]]
```

En esencia el código funciona y hace lo que tiene que hacer, lo cual es lo siguiente: `si el registro tiene 11 caracteres, me trae los primeros 3 caracteres, y en caso de que tenga 12 caracteres, me trae los primeros 4 caracteres.`

Sin embargo demora muchísimo en hacerlo, no se si la comprensión de listas para el tamaño de datos que estoy manejando (aprox. 156,000 registros) es demasiado o que pasa. Por eso buscaba su ayuda para saber si se les ocurre alguna manera que pueda hacer lo mismo que hace este fragmento de código, pero mas eficiente. Actualmente demora aproximadamente una hora en correr solo esa celda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que tienes un ciclo `for`, luego una comprensión de listas y además un `if`

Puedes hacerlo directamente del valor de tu columna con el método [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)

Ya que no pusiste tus datos como texto cree un ejemplo genérico y tendrás que adaptar los nombres de las columnas.

Los datos que estoy utilizando en el archivo "sample2.csv" son estos:

```
asset
10012345678
20012345678
30012345678
40012345678
50012345678
60012345678
70012345678
80012345678
90012345678
1012345678
2012345678
3012345678
4012345678
5012345678
6012345678
7012345678
8012345678
9012345678
0112345678
0212345678
0312345678
0412345678
0512345678
0612345678
0712345678
0812345678
0912345678
1112345678
12123456789
```

En tu ejemplo mencionas que si el `string` es de 10 dígitos deseas obtener los primeros 3 y si es de 11, obtener los primeros 4 y por eso utilizas el `if`, pero en otras palabras, lo que deseas es tomar los caracteres del inicio del `string` hasta el caracter "-7"

Todo lo que tienes se puede reducir a una línea:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', dtype=str)

df['clase'] = df['asset'].str[:-7]
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    asset       clase
0   10012345678 1001
1   20012345678 2001
2   30012345678 3001
3   40012345678 4001
4   50012345678 5001
5   60012345678 6001
6   70012345678 7001
7   80012345678 8001
8   90012345678 9001
9   1012345678  101
10  2012345678  201
11  3012345678  301
12  4012345678  401
13  5012345678  501
14  6012345678  601
15  7012345678  701
16  8012345678  801
17  9012345678  901
18  0112345678  011
19  0212345678  021
20  0312345678  031
21  0412345678  041
22  0512345678  051
23  0612345678  061
24  0712345678  071
25  0812345678  081
26  0912345678  091
27  1112345678  111
28  12123456789 1212
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ayudo mucho

Comment: Por pura curiosidad, ¿Cuánto tiempo redujo?

Comment: Lo hizo inmediatamente, si dijera 3 seg quizá es mucho.

Comment: Lo que sucedía con tu código es que para cada fila recorrías toda la serie y por eso tardaba mucho. Mochilas con la comisión del proyecto =P